# Issue in using multiple databases in laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have developed a project using Laravel 5.2 and I used 2 MySQL connections and configured as given below in `config.database.php`.

```
'mysql1' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'host' => 'localhost',
            'port' => '3306',
            'database' => 'main_data',
            'username' => 'root',
            'password' => 'root',
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'strict' => false,
            'engine' => null,
        ],
        'mysql2' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'host' => 'localhost',
            'port' => '3306',
            'database' => 'second',
            'username' => 'root',
            'password' => 'root',
            'charset' => 'utf8_table',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'strict' => false,
            'engine' => null,
        ],
```

And the model that I want to use second database connection is given below.

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model as Eloquent;

class package extends Eloquent {

    //use HybridRelations;
    protected $connection = 'mysql2';
    protected $table = 'PACKAGE';
...
```

But when I tried to create a new package in controller using `package::create(data)`. it gives error `Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'main_data.package' doesn't exist' in ...`

It seems the model connected to the default connection and when I search the only solution I could found is add `protected $connection = 'mysql2';` which I already did.

Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: Maybe you need to play with the config:cache?

Comment: @mohammad.kaab I tried to clean all the Laravel cache but still same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$connection` attribute in on the `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::class`

change your `Package::class` to extend it

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class package extends Model {

    //use HybridRelations;
    protected $connection = 'mysql2';
    protected $table = 'PACKAGE';
```

Comment: Sorry I could not not mention that I extend the same class as `use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model as Eloquent;`. I'll edit the question

Comment: @VikumDheemantha i can't reproduce your issue on a simple `Model::create()`. There is a bug in laravel 5.2 with relation not having their proper connection loaded but not with direct create. Anyway, try cycling through you table and assign each attribute then call `->save()`